# Masking netCDF data with 2D coordinates using a shapefile

Tags: shapefile, geopandas, shapely, netcdf, 2d

I'm trying to mask netCDF data (with 2D longitude and latitude coordinates) with a shapefile.

---

I have one method, which I can't really finish off and I don't know if I'm doing it right.

```
import fiona
import shapely.geometry
import shapely as sy
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

ds = xr.open_dataset("BW_BY_box.nc")
pr  = ds.pr[0,:,:]*3600
lat = ds.lat[:]
lon = ds.lon[:]

c=fiona.open("shp_by_bw/BAY_BW.shp")
pol=c.next()
geom=shapely.geometry.shape(pol['geometry'])
nlpol=sy.geometry.MultiPolygon(geom)

mask1=np.empty(np.size(lat))

for i in range(0,len(lat)):
    mask1[i]=sy.geometry.Point(lon[i,1],lat[i,0]).within(nlpol)
```

...from then on I don't know how to proceed

---

Then the other method is using geopandas and my code is

```
import geopandas
import rioxarray
import xarray
from shapely.geometry import mapping


ds = xr.open_dataset("BW_BY_box.nc")

ds = xr.open_dataset("BW_BY_box.nc")
pr  = ds.pr[0,:,:]*3600
lat = ds.lat[:]
lon = ds.lon[:]

ds.rio.set_spatial_dims(x_dim="rlon", y_dim="rlat", inplace=True)
ds.rio.write_crs("epsg:4326", inplace=True)
Bay_BW = geopandas.read_file('shp_by_bw/BAY_BW.shp', crs="epsg:4326")
clipped = ds.rio.clip(Bay_BW.geometry.apply(mapping), Bay_BW.crs, drop=False)
```

Here I get an error

```
MissingSpatialDimensionError: x dimension not found. 'rio.set_spatial_dims()' or using 'rename()' 
to change the dimension name to 'x' can address this. Data variable: time_bnds
```

How do I proceed and/or how do I debug the code?

Edit:
Here are attributes and dimension of the netCDF's xarray features
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you also add your coordinates and dimensions for `ds`?

Comment: The error message MissingSpatialDimensionError: x dimension not found. 'rio.set_spatial_dims()' or using 'rename()' to change the dimension name to 'x' can address this. Data variable: time_bnds means that you coordinate variables names rlon and rlat should be changed to x and y Use ds.rename(rlon='x', rlat='y'). Your data variable is in 2D coordinates. Unfortunately, rio.clip currently work only for 1d coordinate variables I myself is trying to do exactly what you tried. I can not find a solution yet.